# Laravel: Download PDF file using JavaScript (axios)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, pdf, download

I have a problem. I am try to download file from Laravel local storage. When i send request i have error 500.

Api.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'ability:admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('files', FilesController::class);
});
```

My request from rest file (REST CLIENT vsCode Extension)

```
GET http://localhost:8000/api/files/wy8NNSV9uAvL0NPYydw5iaZDkz5XQYeFo2A7VZo0.pdf HTTP/1.1
responseType: "blob"
Authorization: Bearer 63|0EyovJatWTlWUX6f2RvfQ228QGlbdZVA5Ldn35FH
Accept: "application/pdf"
Content-Type: "application/pdf"
```

if i send the above request i have error 500

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Host: localhost:8000
Date: Mon, 27 Mar 2023 17:08:09 GMT, Mon, 27 Mar 2023 17:08:09 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.10
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 57
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="auto">
<!--
ValueError: file_get_contents(): Argument #1 ($filename) must not contain any null bytes in file C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\app\Http\Controllers\FilesController.php on line 106

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\app\Http\Controllers\FilesController.php(106): file_get_contents(&#039;%PDF-1.3\n%\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\n...&#039;)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(54): App\Http\Controllers\FilesController-&gt;show(&#039;wy8NNSV9uAvL0NP...&#039;)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\Routing\Controller-&gt;callAction(&#039;show&#039;, Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(260): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher-&gt;dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\FilesController), &#039;show&#039;)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(205): Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;runController()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(798): Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;run()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\sanctum\src\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyAbility.php(28): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyAbility-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), &#039;admin&#039;)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(126): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handleRequest(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), Array)
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), &#039;api&#039;, Object(Closure))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), &#039;api&#039;)
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(45): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), &#039;sanctum&#039;)
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(799): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then(Object(Closure))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(776): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(740): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(729): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then(Object(Closure))
#40 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\public\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 C:\xampp\htdocs\test Laravel\testAuthSanctum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\resources\server.php(16): require_once(&#039;C:\\xampp\\htdocs...&#039;)
#43 {main}
```

if i send request from react i have also error 500

FilesController.php

```
public function show(string $filename)
{

   if(Storage::disk('public')->exists("files/".$filename))
   {
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->get("files/".$filename);
            $content = file_get_contents($path);
            return response($content)->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => mime_content_type($path),
            'Accept' => "application/pdf",
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"'
            ]);
   }
   abort(404);
}
```

Authorization works perfectly. Token is correct. If i try to change `wy8NNSV9uAvL0NPYydw5iaZDkz5XQYeFo2A7VZo0.pdf` to an invalid filename (non-existent) I have a 404 error because the conditional statement will not execute

[files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvgWr.png)

If i change show method to:

```
public function show(string $filename)
{
   if (Storage::disk('public')->exists("files/".$filename)) {
            return Storage::download('public/files/' . $filename, $filename, [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"',
      ]);
   }
}
```

react download it, because the pdf file is blank.

axios method

```
const getFile = (filename) => {  //filename = "wy8NNSV9uAvL0NPYydw5iaZDkz5XQYeFo2A7VZo0.pdf"
    axios.get(
        "http://localhost:8000/api/files/" + filename,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
            responseType: "blob",
            Accept: "application/pdf",
            "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.open(fileURL);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
};
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be in either back-end or front-end.

### Back-end <sup>(Laravel server's side)</sup>

Note that for security reasons, the Browser may block your response if the content does NOT match the given `Content-Type`.

Hence while testing download feature, ensure the file you reply with is a real PDF file.

Once that's done, additionally try something like:

```php
if ( ! file_exists($myAbsoluteFilePath)) {
    abort(404);
}
return response()->download($myAbsoluteFilePath, basename($myAbsoluteFilePath), [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
]);
```

### Front-end <sup>(JavaScript's side)</sup>

Your JS may be wrong, try something like:

```js
axios.get(
  "http://localhost:8000/api/files/" + filename, 
  {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  }
).then((response) => {
  // Parses file, and creates proxy (local data-URL for file).
  var proxy = window.URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/pdf"})
  );

  // Download from proxy.
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(link); // Maybe required by Fire-fox browsers.
  link.href = proxy;
  link.download = "my-file.pdf";
  link.click();

  // Cleanup.
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(proxy);
  link.remove();
});
```

**Or:**

```js
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: "http://localhost:8000/api/files/" + filename,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  }
}).then((response) => {
  // ... Same as above.
});
```

> **Note** that `responseType` is `arraybuffer`.

Comment: i try your code and I have blank pdf with code 200 (OK)

Comment: @MISIU Try `console.log('my response', res);` - I mean, `res.data` may be wrong.

Comment: this is console log: https://pastebin.pl/view/84cf561d

Comment: @MISIU Laravel simply returns the file's binary as content, which is normal for download, but `axios` seems to wrap said binary in `res.data` without encoding to base64, which is invalid JSON. However, see my edit.

Comment: @MISIU See edit, note that responseType is 'arraybuffer', the other changes may only be required for older browsers.

Comment: still blank pdf, if i console log response chrome wrap said binary in ```res.data```. Laravel returns binary data. Why i have still blank pdf? I must resolve this problem. Do you have any idea